# Affect element out of the parent of checkbox by a :checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to use :checked css pseudo-class to hide an element out of the parent of the checkbox . How i can do that ? There an exemple of my probleme:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Element to hide</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use CSS alone to traverse the DOM like that. You'll need some JavaScript.
[CSS DOM Traversal superior than JavaScript DOM Traversal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099222/css-dom-traversal-superior-than-javascript-dom-traversal)

You could use [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) to traverse downwards, but never upwards on the stack.

```js
document.getElementById("checkbox").onchange = (e) => {
  let checked = e.target.checked;
  if (checked) {
    document.getElementById("element-to-hide").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("element-to-hide").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="element-to-hide">Element to hide</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i did that but i was wondering if it was possible in css

Comment: @Binary_Serox It's not. Because you need to traverse the DOM and CSS doesn't have an implementation for DOM traversal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099222/css-dom-traversal-superior-than-javascript-dom-traversal You could use SASS to traverse downwards, but never upwards on the stack.

Comment: okay thanks a lot !

Comment: @Binary_Serox I updated the answer. Make sure you mark it as the correct one! :)